# INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, database, function, postgresql, triggers

I would like to disable the DELETE statement on a table.
What I need to do is a SET a field value instead of removing the respective record.

So far I have tried the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_trg
INSTEAD OF DELETE
ON schema.tbl
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.tbl_delete_fn();
```

My `schema.tbl_delete_fn()` function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.tbl_delete_fn()
  RETURNS trigger AS
BEGIN
  NEW.deleted := true;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
```

So far this doesn't seem to work... any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to define trigger on a view or on a table?

Comment: "Didn't work" ? Exact behaviour, error message, etc?

Answer (score 11):

You want a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger whose function returns `NULL` and the row variable is `OLD`, not `NEW`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_trg
BEFORE DELETE
ON schema.tbl
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.tbl_delete_fn();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.tbl_delete_fn()
  RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  UPDATE schema.tbl SET deleted=true WHERE ctid=OLD.ctid;
  RETURN NULL;
END; ' language plpgsql;
```

Comment: This trigger will block `DELETE` but wont change the row that is deleated.

Comment: @Igor: you're right, edited to use UPDATE instead, tested and it appears to work

Answer (score 6):

Or...

```
CREATE RULE delete_rule 
AS ON DELETE TO schema.tbl
DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

Pros: Clearer, no code is called for each row visited, and no SP required.

Cons: Less standard than the trigger solution.

Comment: But it doesn't update the column of the "not deleted" row.