# ERROR: tuple to be deleted was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have table user that has deleted_at field. To implement the soft deletion I decided to create trigger function that will modify deleted_at field instead of physical deletion. But after that I get such error:

```
ERROR:  tuple to be deleted was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command
HINT:  Consider using an AFTER trigger instead of a BEFORE trigger to propagate changes to other rows.
```

In hint it is said that I can use AFTER trigger but it's not for me as I need to update field before deletion.

So here's my code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION userDeleted() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE user_schema.user_account
        SET deleted_at = NOW()
        WHERE user_id = OLD.user_id;

        RETURN OLD;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER user_soft_delete_trigger
    BEFORE DELETE ON user_schema.user_account
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE userDeleted();
```

I also tried to create trigger like in this question

[tuple to be updated was already modified by an operation triggered by the current command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575426/tuple-to-be-updated-was-already-modified-by-an-operation-triggered-by-the-curren)

But it still not working.

So what can be the problem? If you know, please, tell me. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger (Postgresql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214896/instead-of-delete-trigger-postgresql)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you

```
RETURN OLD;
```

so that the `DELETE` is actually executed. Instead, use

```
RETURN NULL;
```

to abandon the `DELETE`.

Comment: To emphasize/support Laurenz see the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) *Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does not occur for this row)*